# How to make enter key as tab for input and submit if button found in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a view where there are two buttons. one for save and another for update.: I want to use enter key as tab. If it reaches last input and find button, the form will be submitted (ng-click function will be triggered). Is it possible to do with two button or i should rely on only one button?

I tried:

```
     $('#truckform input ,#truckform button').on("keypress", function(e) {
                 // ENTER PRESSED
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                    console.log('tag')
                   // FOCUS ELEMENT
                    var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input");
                    var idx = inputs.index(this);
console.log(idx)

                    console.log(inputs.length)
                    if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
                        inputs[0].select()
                    } else {
                        inputs[idx + 1].focus(); //  handles submit buttons
                        inputs[idx + 1].select();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I gives the error in console when button gets focus:

```
Uncaught TypeError: inputs[(idx + 1)].select is not a function
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (truckEntry.js:56)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
```

But after the error, the saveData() function is triggered. But in the update mode, the updateData() is not triggered and the error remains all times till i press enter. How can i maake it functional? Any suggestion? 
  My view:

```
  <form  name="truckform" id="truckform" novalidate>
               <table id="truckformTbl">
                   <tr>
                       <td class="text-center" colspan="6">
                           <h4 class="ok"> Truck Entry/Exit Form</h4>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                    <tr ng-hide="hideManifestDetailsInput">
                        <th>Manifest No : </th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-pattern='/^[0-9]{1,10}[/]{1}([0-9]{1,2}|[(A|a)]{1})$/' required="required" ng-disabled="disbleManifestNoInpForEditMode"  ng-model="ManifestNo" name="ManifestNo" id="Manifest_no" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Manifest No.">
                            <span class="error" ng-show='truckform.ManifestNo.$error.pattern'>
                                Input like: 256/12 Or 256/A
                            </span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="submitted && !ManifestNo && !truckform.ManifestNo.$error.pattern">
                              Manifest No is required
                            </span>

                            <span class="error" ng-show="truckExceedInManifest">Manifest is full</span>
                        </td>
                        <th>&nbsp; Manifest Date :</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"  ng-model="manifest_date" required="required" name="manifest_date" id="manifest_date" class="form-control datePicker input-sm" placeholder="Manifest date">

                            <span ng-show="submitted && !manifest_date" class="error">Select a date</span>
                        </td>
                        <th>&nbsp;Goods Name :</th>

                        <td style="width: 15em; vertical-align: top" rowspan="8">
                           {{-- <select class="form-control input-sm" name="goods_id" ng-model="goods_id"
                                    ng-options="good.id as good.id +'-'+good.cargo_name group by good.category for good in allGoodsData ">

                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Goods Name</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="truckform.goods_id.$dirty && truckform.goods_id.$touched && !goods_id ">
                             Select at least one goods
                            </span>--}}


                            <tags-input ng-model="goods_id"
                                        display-property="cargo_name"
                                        placeholder="Add New Item"
                                        replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
                                        add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
                                        on-tag-added="tagAdded($tag)"
                                        on-tag-removed="tagRemoved($tag)">

                                <auto-complete source="loadGoods($query)"
                                               min-length="0"
                                               debounce-delay="0"
                                               max-results-to-show="10">

                                </auto-complete>

                            </tags-input>
                            <span ng-show="submitted && !goods_id ||goods_id.length==0" class="error">Choose at least one goods!</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Truck Type :</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="truck_type" name="truck_type" id="truck_type" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{old('truck_type')}}"  placeholder="Truck Type">
                            <span class="error" ng-show="submitted && !truck_type">
                             Truck Type is required
                            </span>
                        </td>

                        <th>&nbsp; Truck No :</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" min="1" required="required" ng-model="truck_no" name="truck_no" id="truckNo" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Truck No" value="{{old('truck_no')}}">
                            <span class="error" ng-show="submitted && !truck_no">
                             Truck No is required
                            </span>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Driver Card No :</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="driver_card" name="DriverCardNo" id="DriverCardNo" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Driver Card No." value="{{old('DriverCardNo')}}">

                            <span class="error" ng-show="submitted && !driver_card">
                             Driver Card No. is required
                            </span>
                        </td>


                        <th> &nbsp;Weight Bridge:</th>
                        <td>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="fff" ng-init="weightment_flag=1"  ng-model="weightment_flag" ng-checked="true"  value="1">Yes
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio"  ng-model="weightment_flag"  value="0" >No
                            </label>
                        </td>



                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                       <th> &nbsp;Driver Name :</th>
                       <td style="width: 15em;">
                           <input type="text" ng-model="driver_name" name="DriverName" id="driverName" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Driver Name" value="{{old('DriverName')}}">
                           <span class="error" ng-show="submitted && !driver_name">
                             Driver Name is required
                            </span>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>

                        <td colspan="1" class="text-center">
                            <br>
                            <button type="button" ng-click="saveData(truckform)" ng-hide="updateBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block center-block">
                                <span class="fa fa-download"></span>
                                Save
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" ng-click="updateData(truckform)" ng-show="updateBtn"  class="btn btn-primary center-block">
                                <span class="fa fa-download"></span>
                                Update
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2"> </td>
                    </tr>

                   <tr>
                       <td colspan="2"></td>
                       <td class="text-center" colspan="3">

                           <div id="success" class="col-md-12 alert alert-success" ng-show="successMsg">
                               Successfully @{{ successMsgTxt }}!
                           </div>

                           <div id="error" class="col-md-12 alert alert-warning" ng-show="errorMsg">
                                @{{ errorMsgTxt }}!
                           </div>
                       </td>
                       <td colspan="1"> </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
```

Comment: In html form whenever you use with ng-submit and a button/input with type="submit" will work for you when you hit enter. For form validation you can refere [here](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html) - for update/save logic you can control it inside controller based on the flag

Comment: so, you suggest to use one button in view? i wanted to get help how can i use enter key as tab. Please read my question.

Comment: in your case you are using two buttons with `ng-hide & ng-show` with type="button" so when you hit enter it will always trigger the first button, bec. it only hides the button with `display:none` but actually two buttons in the DOM. so please use ng-if. you can see my answer for detailed answer. and with this you don't need to use enter as tab key here

Answer (score 1):

Here you do not need to bind keypress events for input, by default in forms if you have buttons and if you hit enter, it will trigger the first button's click event,
if you have button's type as submit and if you hit enter when you are inside any of your input it will trigger form submit automatically. The example as like below.

I edited my original answer and now it acts as tab when you press enter key. Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejrk982w/27/)

```
<body class="container" ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="truckForm" ng-submit="submit(truckForm.$valid)" class="form-horizontal container" enter-to-tab>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{btnFlag}}</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

and in your controller

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl)
        .directive('enterToTab', enterToTab);

    myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function myCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.updateBtn = true;
        $scope.submit = submit;

        function submit(valid) {
            console.log('hi', valid);
            if ($scope.updateBtn && valid) {
                updateData(/* your params if any */);
            } else if (valid) {
                saveData(/* your params if any */);
            }
        }

        function saveData(/* your params if any */) {
            console.log('save');
            // do your save action here
        }

        function updateData(/* your params if any */) {
            console.log('update');
            // do your update action here
        }
    }


    function enterToTab() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, attrs, element) {
                var elm = angular.element(element.$$element[0]);
                var inputs = angular.element('input', elm);
                var length = inputs.length - 1;
                var submit = angular.element('button[type=submit]', elm);
                inputs.on('keydown', function(e) {
                    if (e.which === 13) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var index = inputs.index(this);
                        if (index === length && submit.length) {
                            submit.focus();
                        } else if(index === length) {
                            inputs[0].focus();
                        } else {
                            inputs[index + 1].focus();
                        }
                    }   
                })
            }
        };
    }
```

Here `type="submit"` for button is important. And avoid any jquery like dom manipulations when you are developing an angularjs application, so I made it in angular way of doing this with directive. I have added `enter-to-tab` in `form` tag at HTML

Comment: OK. One thing you should notice that I also need to set focus on next input when enter key is pressed instead of submitting the form. Using  my question code I can do that. But the problem is that when it reaches on the button, it gives the error I mentioned. I need to check if is button . And it is button, then ng-click event should be triggered. Otherwise the focus must go to next input. @kanagu

Comment: Your is code may be used as I planed to use one button instead of two. Thanks for your help!@kanagu

Comment: Hi Fawel, I have edited my answer to suite your requirement (enter to tab key). As we are preventing default action for enter key you have to do your validation programatically..

Answer (score 0):

You can use enter key as tab as follows:

```
  $('input').bind("keypress", function(e) {
     // ENTER PRESSED
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().focus(); 
      }
    }
  });
```

Small plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xeRqbMD0LDVWXj7tz82k?p=preview)